# How can i get mailItem when replying to an email?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I wrote an outlook vsto addin that converts files added via the button on the ribbon into links. First, I click on the create link button on the ribbon and select the files to be uploaded. Then I upload the files and add them to the body of the mail. There is no problem when i create a new mail.

But when I try to create a file link and attach it to the mail body after clicking reply or replyall in an email, the link I want to attach added to the mail in the inbox, not to the reply screen. If I click reply and open in a new tab, there is no problem because the inspector is not null. In short, when I click the reply mail, I cannot get the correct mailItem object how can i get right one?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();

if (inspector == null)
{
    mi = (MailItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];

    if (mi == null)
    {
        return;
    }

}
else
{
    mi = (MailItem)inspector.CurrentItem;
}
```

I'm using this code to get mailItem.

[image]

I'm trying to add the link to the green area in the image above but it changes the body of the email in the inbox and adds it there.

[image]

As you can see, the link has been added to the body of the previously received email in the inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the inline response, use `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().ActiveInlineResponse`

But you can have both a standalone inspector and an inline response. You really need to check what `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow` returns, `Inspector` or `Explorer`.